# How can you use std::setw() with array output?

Tags: c++, vector, console, cout

I am making a blackjack game in C++, and I am trying to print out the players and dealers cards in addition to their sums, capital and so on. However I'm running into an issue with `std::setw()` when printing out the vector of cards. Here is a code snippet:

```
    int width = 18;
    std::cout << std::left << std::setw(width) << "Your cards:";
    std::cout << std::left << std::setw(width * 2) << "arr";
    std::cout << std::left << std::setw(width) << "Dealers cards:";
    std::cout << "arr2" << std::endl;

    std::cout << std::left << std::setw(width) << "Your sum:";
    std::cout << std::left << std::setw(width*2) << player.sum();
    std::cout << std::left << std::setw(width) << "Dealers sum:";
    std::cout << dealer.sum() << std::endl;
```

[image: What my code snippet looks like]

Where `arr` and `arr2` is there should be number values like `5 2 6 1`, but if I print each element separately the with alignment will break. I think for `setw()` to work it needs to be one block or string, or else the vertical alignment will mess up once the values change. I tried `myString.push_back()` for each vector value and then printing that, with no luck. I assume I need to find a way to print the string into one element.

This is what it should look like:

```
Your cards:     5 7 1 2                 Dealers cards:     2 1 7 5
Your sum:       21                      Dealers sum:       21
Your capital:   100                     Dealers capital:   100
```

Comment: Does it matter if the space between both columns is exactly the number of spaces? You could only apply `std::setw` when printing the last number in the array.

Comment: It doesn't matter, however the question then is what the width number should be - keep in mind that the array can span from 2 - 6 or more numbers. The important thing is that the columns are straight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution. You can use stringstream to add int values to a string with no errors in conversion, this is how I fixed my code:

```
#include <sstream>
std::stringstream playerCards{};

for (int i{}; i < player.cards.size(); i++) {
    playerCards << player.cards[i] << " ";
}

int width = 18;
std::cout << std::left << std::setw(width) << "Your cards:";
std::cout << std::left << std::setw(width * 2) << playerCards.str();
```

This way the array will get put into a string and will count as one block, which is what I was looking for.